# Ionic 1 with Angular JS 1 or Angular JS 2

Tags: android, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am a beginner in hybrid app development. I know there is Ionic version 1 and 2(unofficial release). There is also a Angular JS version 1 and 2 (unofficial release). The following are my questions

1. Can I use Angular JS 2 with Ionic version 1 instead of Angular JS 1?
2. Do companies use Ionic 2 and/or Angular JS 2 as it is not an official release yet?
3. What combination is currently used for production apps by companies currently?
4. Can I use regular JavaScript(not angular) with Ionic 1 or 2?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Yes, they use. No, you probably shouldn't. If you have these questions, Angular 2 + Ionic 2 is certainly not for you. Being an early adopter of unreleased product is PITA, a questionable pleasure for a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cents,

***1) Can I use Angular JS 2 with Ionic version 1 instead of Angular JS 1?***

No you can't, Ionic2 is build from ground up for Angular2/TypeScript.

***2) Do companies use Ionic 2 and/or Angular JS 2 as it is not an official release yet?***

I don't have any numbers, but I believe Ionic2/Angular2 is too new to have many production apps **Yet**. But it doesn't mean that ng2/Ionic2 are not out there.

***3) What combination is currently used for production apps by companies currently?***

As I mentioned in (2), I believe its mostly Angular 1 and Ionic 1 still. Because if you have a fairly big mobile app. Its not easy to migrate to Angular2/Ionic2 straight away. Also since as company point of view its sensible to use a stable framework.

***4) Can I use regular JavaScript (not angular) with Ionic 1 or 2?***

With Ionic1 you defiantly can, with Ionic2, there is not drop-in solution but there are ways to integrate normal [JavaScript with Ionic2](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-typings/)

If you are starting new, I would recommend to go with Angular2/Ionic2 and TypeScript (this is assuming you don't have any app that should go on production in near future). Reason being,

1 - Angular2/Ionic2 is vastly differ from Angular1/Ionic1. So not having a knowledge with version 1 will not effect you on learning Ver2

2 - Angular2/Ionic2 uses component based architecture, which means you app will build as components are its very easy to understand.

3 - Angular2/Ionic2 uses classes, modules etc... So if you have a knowledge in any other OO programming language (E.g Ruby, Java etc) you'll feel right at home.

4 - After some time, there will be more resource for Angular2/Ionic2 than the version 1 and soon version 1 will be obsolete. Tech world time is 10x faster than the normal world time :).

Answer (score 0):

Although Ionic 2 supports lots of helpful UI Components than Ionic 1,
but it has not released yet, and has some issues to fix and not fully with cordova plugins.

I recommend you to use Ionic 1.x and Angular 1.x for your apps.

Comment: I agree. Work with Ionic 1 Angular 1 and then when time is ripe shift to Ionic 2 Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Can I use Angular JS 2 with Ionic version 1 instead of Angular JS 1?**
   - you cannot use angularjs 2 with ionic 1, because of typescript in angularjs 2.